# "input-validation-error" class will not added to that text box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have registered below javascript in my view of mvc3 application.

```
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

I have also added below keys to my web.config.

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

I have also added required attribute with error message above the text box but when I submit the form with blank value in text box "input-validation-error" class will not added to that text box.

Please tell me the reason why "input-validation-error" class will not added while submit the form.???

Thanks in advance.

Jayesh Ginoya

Comment: I am having the same problem, where using the `.form-control` class from Bootstrap 3 will override the `border` styling of jquery.validate's `.input-validation-error` (a default ASP.NET MVC project will include a style for this in the generated file `Site.css`). I think I will remove the `border-color` styling from `.form-control` in Bootstrap's less files, because I was not able to override this property due to unusual "CSS specificity" issues.